# Unable to configure Sendmail to use Gmail

Tags: ubuntu, gmail, sendmail, ubuntu-10.04

I gave configured sendmail to use gmail. This is the output which I get but i am not getting the mail. what may be the problem

```
prashanth@prashanth-laptop:~$ sendmail -v *********.*******@gmail.com < test.mail
WARNING: local host name (prashanth-laptop) is not qualified; see cf/README: WHO AM I?
*********.*******@gmail.com... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
220 prashanth-laptop ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.3/8.14.3/Debian-9.1ubuntu1; Fri, 2 Sep 2011 12:31:15 +0530; (No UCE/UBE) logging access from: localhost(OK)-localhost [127.0.0.1]
>>> EHLO prashanth-laptop
250-prashanth-laptop Hello localhost [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-EXPN
250-VERB
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
2    50-ETRN
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
>>> VERB
250 2.0.0 Verbose mode
>>> MAIL From:<prashanth@prashanth-laptop> SIZE=45
250 2.1.0 <prashanth@prashanth-laptop>... Sender ok
>>> RCPT To:<*********.*******@gmail.com>
>>> DATA
250 2.1.5 <*********.*******@gmail.com>... Recipient ok
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
>>> .
050 <*********.*******@gmail.com>... Connecting to smtp.gmail.com port 587 via relay...
050 220 mx.google.com ESMTP e3sm8203378pbi.7
050 >>> EHLO prashanth-laptop
050 250-mx.google.com at your service, [117.197.206.85]
050 250-SIZE 35882577
050 250-8BITMIME
050 250-STARTTLS
050 250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
050 >>> STARTTLS
050 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
050 >>> EHLO prashanth-laptop
050 250-mx.google.com at your service, [117.197.206.85]
0    50 250-SIZE 35882577
050 250-8BITMIME
050 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH
050 250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
050 >>> MAIL From:<prashanth@prashanth-laptop> SIZE=353
050 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at                              
050 530 5.5.1 http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 e3sm8203378pbi.7
050 <prashanth@prashanth-laptop>... Connecting to local...
050 <prashanth@prashanth-laptop>... Sent
250 2.0.0 p8271FSG017551 Message accepted for delivery
*********.*******@gmail.com... Sent (p8271FSG017551 Message accepted for delivery)
Closing connection to [127.0.0.1]
>>> QUIT
221 2.0.0 prashanth-laptop closing connection
```

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to use port 587 but you are not authenticating.

Do you understand the warning and error messages? You will also need to have the FQDN added to your outgoing mail.

Is there a particular reason you are using Sendmail? I would recommend Postfix if you do not have strong reasons to stick with Sendmail.